# How to validate two forms separately in html5

Tags: html, forms, validation

I have a login form and registration form placed side by side. I have applied the required field validation for all the textboxes in both the forms. My problem is that when i try to login it validates the registration form also. Is there any validation group like control available for HTML5 like the one present for ASP.Net...

Comment: A validation group in HTML is "a form". I created two forms with required fields, when the field wasn't filled out the form wouldn't submit, when it was the form would submit (even if the field in the other form, also required, was left blank). I can't reproduce the problem you describe.

Comment: Sorry, it was a careless mistake. I hadn't closed the form tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are the two forms completely separated? If there is an error in the HTML (a missing end-tag, for example) then they may be considered as part of one form.